# Error when minting with CLI

Tags: plutus-pioneer-program, cardano-cli

I tried to follow Lars' instructions on minting with CLI and I get the error below. I did not modify `cabal.project`. Any idea what goes wrong?

```
./mint-token-cli.sh f8a3850921711b4d8ad1e467f38640000a7d1ad99e076a286d0b3999450b86b1#0 123456 PPP testnet/01.addr testnet/01.skey
oref: f8a3850921711b4d8ad1e467f38640000a7d1ad99e076a286d0b3999450b86b1#0
amt: 123456
tn: PPP
address file: testnet/01.addr
signing key file: testnet/01.skey
cabal: Error parsing project file
/home/mcodescu/repos/Plutus/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week06/cabal.project:46:
"<eitherParsec>" (line 2, column 1):
unexpected 'p'
expecting space or end of input

cabal: Error parsing project file
/home/mcodescu/repos/Plutus/plutus-pioneer-program/code/week06/cabal.project:46:
"<eitherParsec>" (line 2, column 1):
unexpected 'p'
expecting space or end of input

currency symbol: 15a3588ebd4ab3ef669bca21021836e3914fb0c6f3ba0c34ace0b4a4
token name (hex): 
minted value: 123456 15a3588ebd4ab3ef669bca21021836e3914fb0c6f3ba0c34ace0b4a4.
address: addr_test1vr0g9yze75lahhygqs5kg7x8m4as0tnj6k2gpe9ng8vlp0q9wdl2v
Command failed: transaction build  Error: The following scripts have execution failures:
the script for policyId 0 (in the order of the PolicyIds) failed with: 
The Plutus script evaluation failed: An error has occurred:  User error:
The provided Plutus code called 'error'.
Script debugging logs: wrong amount minted
PT5


Command failed: transaction sign  Error: testnet/tx.unsigned: testnet/tx.unsigned: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
Command failed: transaction submit  Error: testnet/tx.signed: testnet/tx.signed: openBinaryFile: does not exist (No such file or directory)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, my bad, you have to do this from the nix shell.